# A question about numpy ndarray transformation

Tags: numpy

any simple way to change this array

```
[[ 3  4  0  1  2]
 [ 8  9  5  6  7]
 [13 14 10 11 12]]
```

into:

```
[[ 0  0  0  1  2]
 [ 0  0  5  6  7]
 [ 0  0 10 11 12]]
```

?

Edit: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 306 for transpose

Comment: Are you just replacing the first 2 columns with 0?  (What's that edit about?  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing):

```py
>>> a[:,:2] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: I guess it's fast. @TonyLucas you are new to SO so "if it helps you then please upvote answer or accept the answer if you think this is what you are looking for."